# Xcode: How to exclude Pods and Target Support Files when merging branches?

Tags: xcode, git, git-merge

In Xcode, I am trying to merge branch B with A. However, when I do the merge, I see many conflicts in the Pods and Target support files between the two branches.

I added the Pods folder to my gitignore (in both branches), and I committed and pushed the gitignore as well, but I still see the Pods files in Xcode when starting the merge.

How do I completely exclude the Pods folder when merging?